mysql insert ignore is still inserting duplicate values
I am reading columns/values (which could have dozens of duplicates) from TableA and need to insert unique records into Table B.  Table B is an empty table, has a primary key and has a 5 column unique index.  I am using insert ignore into TableB but every duplicate record (from TableA) is still getting inserted into TableB.
Please help me understand what I am doing wrong with my inserts.
TableB (aka: userComms) structure and indexes:
| userComms | CREATE TABLE `userComms` (
  `commsID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_ID` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `commsType` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `crID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `clID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ceID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `push` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `email` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `text` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`commsID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `comm_index` (`user_ID`,`cID`,`crID`,`clID`,`ceID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=71926 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |

Below is just one insert example, it should see a duplicate on: user_ID,cID,crID,clID,ceID and NOT insert the next record with the same index values.
TableA Rows to insert: (PHP)
foreach ($tableA as $rowA) {
  $query = "insert ignore into userComms (user_ID,commsType,cID,crID,clID,ceID,push,email,text) VALUES ($row['user_ID'],$row['commsType'],$row['clubID'],null,null,null,1,1,1)"
   ...
}

In the above insert I see should each unique index only once, but multiple inserts are happening on the same values:
select * from userComms where user_ID='20230723_190383173' and cID=1001 ;
+---------+--------------------+-----------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+------+
| commsID | user_ID            | commsType | cID  | crID | clID | ceID | push | email | text |
+---------+--------------------+-----------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+------+
|   63462 | 20230723_190383173 |         1 | 1001 | NULL | NULL | NULL |    1 |     1 |    1 |
|   71834 | 20230723_190383173 |         1 | 1001 | NULL | NULL | NULL |    1 |     1 |    1 |


Can you post tables using show create table table_name command rather than using desc? It is more helpful

All NULLs are unique. So your rows are NOT duplicates - their NULLs differs. Create functional unique index and replace possible NULLs with some constant value which the column should not contain (for example, -1).

@ErgestBasha - I updated the OP with show create table  command

@Akina - how are NULLs unique?  I never heard that before.  if they are unique how would a where thisID IS NULL work if all NULLs are not the same NULL?  I will reset table and replace null with '0 value and see what happens.

@Akina - well crap...that worked!  I thought part of the purpose of UNIQUE INDEX was that it could have NULL values unlike a Primary Key.  Please do a formal ANSWER and I will accept it to give you credit....in the answer please explain how NULLs are unique, still scratching my head on that one.

@rolinger Null values are strange. That's why you have to use x IS NULL rather than x = NULL.

If I don't tell you my age, and you don't tell me your age, does that mean we are the same age?

a new way of thinking of it i suppose, I always assume NULL={nothing}.  Thanks guys.

MariaDB's info had this: The fact that a UNIQUE constraint can be NULL is often overlooked. In SQL any NULL is never equal to anything, not even to another NULL. Consequently, a UNIQUE constraint will not prevent one from storing duplicate rows if they contain null values ... but I could not find the same in MySQL's info, but very likely the same reason? I found that in their unique index information See that link for an example below that explanation. Perhaps @Akina meant all nulls are not unique?

I always assume NULL={nothing}. NULL == {UNKNOWN}. Does one UNKNOWN is equal to another UNKNOWN? this is UNKNOWN... which obviously is not TRUE and hence it is interpreted as FALSE.
